# Can I secure an MVC Core web application with JWTs only?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, jwt

I have a Core Web API protected by JWTs, and this service is consumed, via `HttpClient`, by a WPF application. This all works nicely because once I have a token I pass it in a header with each request.

Now I need to build an MVC Core web application that uses some of the functionality of the API. To avoid CORS issues, I would like to import the API controllers into the web application. However, I don't want to mix cookie and JWT auth.

Normally in the WPF application, for login, I make a request to my API's `Token` controller, get the token and use it to authorize subsequent requests. Now I can build a login page in the main MVC application that calls into my `Token` controller with `HttpClient` and gets a JWT, but then how do I use that token to authorize all other actions in the main MVC app. It also seems very clumsy to have to use `HttpClient` to pass the JWT header for internal calls.

Is there a way I can secure my MVC application from the start with JWTs without having to use `HttpClient`. That is, once I have my token, and all actions are secured by tokens, how do I store and pass that token for all other requests to the main MVC app?

Comment: I needed something similar and I ended up with JWT stored directly in cookie. API.Token and Account.Login operations generate same JWT so I could secure API method, and Web actions using same technique.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on if you are building an SPA.  JWT tokens will not automatically be served by a browser, only cookies will.  So if you aren't building an SPA where you could explicitly send each request with the token added, then you would need to use cookies or store the JWT in a session and then append it to the outgoing request to the api.

To get around the CORS issue, I would use a tool like refit, which allows you to make an interface into boilerplate webrequests.  These have extensibility points to allow you to append a header before the request is made.

Optionally, I method I have used before is to create a proxy controller that handles all requests to a set url structure (like 'api/...') and then forwards those to the API server by copying all the body/headers into a new request and then copy the response into the response object in the controller for returning through the browser.  This too will allow you to inject the JWT into the header.

Comment: I think you misunderstand me. I don't want to have a client web application and a separate API. I want to have just one web application, but with requests authorized with a JWT instead of cookies. This is so that a separate WPF app can get a JWT and access some API controllers in the web app, not in an API.

Comment: As i mentioned in the answer, a browser initiated request will not append the JWT authorization header.  That can be done by making your site an SPA and having javascript request all your pages and then appending the header to it.  Otherwise, you will need to store the JWT in a cookie instead.